# How to use sql IN query in SQL heredoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to use constant of an array  in SQL heredoc like:

```
ROLES = ['admin', 'staff', 'guest']

query = <<-SQL
  SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE role IN (#{ROLES})
SQL

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

but getting syntax error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 2: WHERE role IN (["admin", "staff", "guest"])
                       ^
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` for such a query?

Comment: @SebastianPalma here I am using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)` just to demonstrate the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the result of `ROLES.inspect`, you should make the string with roles yourself, I would use `map` and `join` for that purpose:

```
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE role IN (#{ROLES.map { |role| "'#{role}'" }.join(',')})
SQL
ApplicationRecord.connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: `ROLES.join(',')` will reproduce like `WHERE role IN ('admin, staff,  guest')` but it must be like `WHERE role IN ('admin', 'staff',  'guest')`

Comment: Right, how about now?

Comment: Note that this can still fail if the any of the `ROLES` include a `'` character, and is susceptible to SQL injection if the dynamic data comes from an external user. Both shouldn't be an issue when looking at the question. But since OP says *"here I am using ... just to demonstrate the situation"* I thought it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building your own Ruby to SQL converter you could also make use of the [arel](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/) gem which already does the necessary escaping and quoting.

```
users = User.arel_table
```

```
ApplicationRecord.connection.execute(<<~SQL.squish)
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE #{users[:role].in(ROLES).to_sql}
SQL
```

Or if you'd like to go full arel.

```
ApplicationRecord.connection.execute(
  users.project(users[Arel.star])
       .where(users[:role].in(ROLES))
       .to_sql
)
```

Comment: Or, if you need/want to go with straight SQL, use `connection.quote` to properly quote the strings.

Comment: @muistooshort I didn't know about that helper. Seems pretty handy, but might be better suited for [Marek Lipka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60929245/3982562), since that answer maps over the `ROLES` and quotes them.